# How to stop Thymealeaf from overwriting data sent to the View?

Tags: html, spring-boot, jdbc, thymeleaf

I am trying to get a Bootstrap table to display my MySQL database (in a Spring Boot project where I use JDBC, so without any ORM so far). I am using Thymeleaf to send my ResultSet rs to the front end, but it is currently showing the second row of my two-row database twice.

The table is presented like this in my Homepage.html file:

```html
<table id="allQuizzesTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Quiz ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Created by </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="ID : ${IDList}">
        <td th:text="${ID}"></td>
        <td th:text="${Title}"></td>
        <td th:text="${Category}"></td>
        <td th:text="${Author}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my Controller method so far (it is messy but I don't know what to move where yet):

```java
@GetMapping(path="/home")
public String HomeString(Model model){
    ArrayList<String> IDList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("...");//works at this point
        Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        st.executeUpdate("use quiz;");
        
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM quiz;"); 
        while (rs.next()) {
            IDList.add(rs.getString(1));
            model.addAttribute("ID", rs.getString(1));
            model.addAttribute("Title", rs.getString(2));
            model.addAttribute("Category", rs.getString(4));
            model.addAttribute("Author", rs.getInt(3));
        }
        model.addAttribute("IDList", IDList);
        st.close();
```

I checked my ResultSet with `System.out.println(rs.getString(2));` in the middle of my while loop and I do get the expected titles. So I suppose the issue occurs on the HTML side.
Any help is appreciated. I haven't found anything similar (in terms of using strict JDBC with MySQL and Bootstrap/Thymeleaf) so I'm open to completely new alternatives as well.

Comment: You are overwriting the attribute ID, Title, Category, Author yourself in the loop!

Comment: Hi! I do get that but I'm not sure how to go around it, I'm aware it's a silly question. Is creating an object that groups all the attributes and adding it to a list of quizzes that's sent to the view the only solution? I haven't seen anything 'simpler'.

Comment: How could it be simpler than that?

Comment: Create your own `Quiz` class. Instead of `ArrayList<String>` use `List<Quiz>`. In your `while (rs.next())` loop, create each new `quiz` object and add it to the list. Use that list of quiz objects in your model. Generally, you gain a lot of benefits by doing that small amount of up-front extra work (in this case, creating a class to represent your quiz data) instead of trying to juggle the individual fields returned from the database.

Comment: I created an object and it's fixed. Thank you, I guess I needed that extra push. I was resisting making objects to avoid the 'extra code' and embrace JDBC functionality. Turns out it became necessary, I'll update my post!

Comment: The second part of your question should be posted as an **answer**.

Answer (score 1):

My problem came from JDBC prejudice. Retrieving all the rows from a table as a concatenated String works without objects (what I had so far). Many JDBC tutorials seem to overcomplicate objects with mapping or annotations (a.k.a. adding issues if you're working against the time and/or still learning). You usually pick JDBC believing 'less is more' but objects might become unavoidable just when you arrive to front-end matters.

My controller now:

```
List<Quiz> quizzes = new ArrayList<>(); 
//connection stuff
while (rs.next()) {
    Quiz DBquiz = new Quiz();
    DBquiz.setQuizId(rs.getInt(1));
    //all the other setters
    quizzes.add(DBquiz);
}
model.addAttribute("quizzes", quizzes);
st.close();
```

And what a line of my revised HTML looks like `<td th:text="${DBquiz.getAuthorId()}"></td>` . (I was skeptical about a Java method in the middle of my HTML file, this is re-enforcement for the odd lost beginner.)

Comment: "_objects might become unavoidable_" - When I started learning Java, I used strings and arrays to _avoid_ needing to create my own custom objects. I found myself constantly fighting against Java as a result.  The more you use Java objects, the more you may well find you _want_ to use Java objects. Don't avoid them, embrace them.